# How to get number of day between two text box in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get number of day between two text boxes but how do I convert from date to integer by using JavaScript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc(a,b,sub) {
    var one = parseInt(a);
    if (isNaN(one)) {
        alert('Invalid entry: '+a);
        one=0;
    }
    var two = parseInt(document.getElementById(b).value);
    if (isNaN(two)) {
        alert('Invalid entry: '+b);
        two=0;
    }
    document.getElementById(sub).value =two-one;
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="Itm_1" id="datepicker1" onchange="calc(Date.parse(this.value),'datepicker1','result')" required="" style="width:205px;" placeholder="<?php echo Date(" d/m/Y ");?>"/>
<input type="text" name="Itm_2" id="datepicker2" onchange="calc(Date.parse(this.value),'datepicker2','result')"  required="" style="width:205px;" placeholder="<?php echo Date(" d/m/Y ");?>"/>
<textarea name="Itm_3" id="result" id="result" cols="30" rows="5" style="height:50px;" value="" readonly=""></textarea>
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: <input type="text" name="Itm_1" id="datepicker1" onchange="calc(Date.parse(this.value),'datepicker1','result')" required="" style="width:205px;" placeholder="<?php echo Date(" d/m/Y ");?>"/>

Comment: <input type="text" name="Itm_2" id="datepicker2" onchange="calc(Date.parse(this.value),'datepicker2','result')"  required="" style="width:205px;" placeholder="<?php echo Date(" d/m/Y ");?>"/>                
<textarea name="Itm_3" id="result" id="result" cols="30" rows="5" style="height:50px;" value="" readonly=""></textarea>

Comment: All right let me see

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Date object, the following site claims you can get the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1st, 1970 using the parse() method.  If you want the integer in days, you can divide by (1000*60*60*24):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

The following should work, if I'm understanding what it is intended to do properly (note changes to HTML inputs).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc(a,b,sub) {
    var one = (Date.parse(document.getElementById(a).value)/(1000*60*60*24));
    if (isNaN(one)) {
          alert('Invalid entry: '+a);
          one=0;
    }
    var two = (Date.parse(document.getElementById(b).value)/(1000*60*60*24));
    if (isNaN(two)) {
        alert('Invalid entry: '+b);
        two=0;
    }
    document.getElementById(sub).value =two-one;
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="Itm_1" id="datepicker1" onchange="calc('datepicker1','datepicker2','result')" required="" style="width:205px;" />
<input type="text" name="Itm_2" id="datepicker2" onchange="calc('datepicker1','datepicker2','result')"  required="" style="width:205px;" />
<textarea name="Itm_3" id="result" id="result" cols="30" rows="5" style="height:50px;" value="" readonly=""></textarea>
```

Comment: Looks like DOM beat me to it and gave a more complete answer.  Well done, DOM!

Comment: The answer is incorrect when i click pick a date from the datetimepicker it show error message